# How I do for() statement for append() content?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, append

I `append()` input type radio to form:

```
$('<input type="radio" id="o1" name="on1" value="1" />').appendTo('#form');
$('<input type="radio" id="o2" name="on2" value="2" />').appendTo('#form');
$('<input type="radio" id="o3" name="on3" value="3" />').appendTo('#form');
```

Now I need to find out who is active:

```
 var question = 0;

 for (var a = 1, b = 3; a <= b; a++) {
        if($('#o'+ a).is(':checked')) question = 1;
 }
```

Why does it not?

Thank you.

For use `append()` content is function like this:

```
$("#form").on("change", "#o1", function() {
    if (this.checked)
        question = 1;
});
```

What function is for `for()`?

Comment: This does not makes sense. You probably want to check statement upon  an *event*. what event you use for that?

Comment: No. This is only for example.
I have form with add button for imput.
And after append i need check this input status.

Comment: Than say it :) you question as it stands is really hard to understand.

Comment: Are you perchance appending several elements with the same id `one`? Keep in mind `id` attributes must be unique within an HTML document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `change` event for that newly added element via event delegation:

```
$("#form").on("change", "#one", function() {
    if (this.checked)
        alert("yes");
});
```

Keep in mind if you're appending multiple elements like this that ID's **must** be unique! I recommend using a common class, as ID's are not always needed on elements.

Comment: Seems exactly what the OP needs. Just look at Frédéric comment to append a nice suggestion.

Comment: YES, this is a solutions. But as can I do for() function, for inputs who I do by append()?

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you're asking